# Как через adb shell указать номер телефона для эмулятора Android

Tags: android, shell, adb

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно через `adb shell` изменить номер в эмуляторе Android?

Comment: Номер чего? Разве эмулятор поддерживается SIM?

Comment: @Игорь никак через adb shell

Comment: @Игорь, что значит "указать?"

Comment: service call iphonesubinfo 8 через эту  можно узнать виртуальный номер. А как через код его можно изменить?